# Open GL ES not rendering on iPhone but works in simulator?

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es

My OpenGL ES code works fine in the simulator and I did not touch threading at all. Perhaps it is a iOS version issue? Game is still updating and render methods are being called. Touch still works. It is just that rendering is not working. So what may be a possible cause of this?

Comment: Have you tried logging the current opengl error at various points in your program? What happens when you do a frame capture?

Comment: This happened to me once before, it was because I called a gles 1.1 function in a 2.0 context.

Comment: The screen still clears to the correct colour as specified by me, however, I am not using any 1.* functions. functions like:
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc();

Comment: @BenPious did your app work in the simulator?

Comment: Yes. That's why I said "it happened to me once before." Try the frame capture and the error logging (put NSLog(@"CurrentGlError: %d at line %d", glGetError(), __LINE__) around openGL calls in your program to see if they cause an error), they'll help you narrow down the problem to a specific section of code. Without finding the relevant code to post anyone who answers this is just speculating.

Comment: Nope no error at most of my lines of code. I did a screen capture and i realised that nothing was being drawn to the screen while in another app something was being drawn